# MVC Controller, connecting to WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

So i got a MVC application which gets it's data from a WCF.
The problem I got in my controller atm is that it won't link a ServiceClient with a Model.

Here is my code:

```
  public DBService.DataServiceClient DB = new DBService.DataServiceClient();
    public WedstrijdService.IWedstrijdService WedService = new WedstrijdService.IWedstrijdService();
    public ActionResult WedstrijdViewMain(int OrgID, int TeamID)
    {
        Models.Wedstrijden.WedstrijdModel WM = new Models.Wedstrijden.WedstrijdModel();
        DBService.DataServiceClient DB = new DBService.DataServiceClient();

        var wedstrijden = WedService.GetWedstrijd(TeamID, OrgID);


        return View(WedService);
    }
```

I know the IWedstrijdService has to be WedstrijdServiceClient, but that one doesn't get recognised.
Also it shows up as an interface while it has to be a class.
Can anyone help me out a bit where to edit stuff in the WCF/MVC code.

Comment: Can you explain why you have `DBService.DataServiceClient DB = new DBService.DataServiceClient()` outside your method and also inside? What do you mean when you say it doesn't get recognised, can you tell us the error? Perhaps include the whole class file so we can understand better what you're doing.

Comment: You should instantiate the `...Client` and not the Service it self. `var service = new DBService.DataServiceClient();` then just use the client for calling the actions. `service..GetWedstrijd(TeamID, OrgID);`

Answer (score 0):

Just create object of you service.

**Example:**

```
public ActionResult WedstrijdViewMain(int OrgID, int TeamID)
    {
       DBService.DataServiceClient DBObject = new DBService.DataServiceClient();//Create Object of your service
            var wedstrijden = DBObject.GetWedstrijd(TeamID, OrgID);
       return View(WedService);
    }
```